# In iMovie, how to put multiple picture-in-picture?

Tags: imovie

I'm trying to put two black boxes on my clip two block two names, and every YouTube tutorial tells me to export after placing the first box and do the trick again. How do I put multiple simultaneous picture-in-picture in iMovie *actually*? (It cannot possibly be the only way!)